# MIPS Recursion Program

Tags: recursion, mips

I am new to MIPS, and am trying to write a recursive program. The program will compute `f(N)`, where `N` is an integer greater than zero. `f(N)= 3*(N-1)+f(N-1)+1`. The base case is `f(0)=2`. However, when I try running my program it keeps running indefinitely, so I am guessing the recursive calls never end. I can't seem to locate where the problem is though. My code is as follows.

```
    .data
    prompt: .asciiz "Please enter a number"

    .text
    .globl main

    main:
        li $v0, 4 
        la $a0, prompt 
        syscall 
        li $v0, 5
        syscall
        move $a0, $v0
        jal factfunc
        move $a0, $v0
        li $v0, 1
        syscall
        li $v0, 10
        syscall

   factfunc:
        addiu $sp, $sp, -8
        sw $ra, 4($sp)
        sw $s0, 0($sp)
        move $s0, $a0
        blez $s0, endCondition
        addi $a0, $a0, -1
        jal factfunc
        li $s1, 0
        li $s2, 0
        addi $s1, $s0, -1
        move $s2, $s1
        addu $s2, $s2, $s2
        addu $s1, $s2, $s1
        addu $v0, $v0, $s1
        addi $v0, $v0, 1

  cleanUp: 
       lw $s0, 0($sp)
       lw $ra, 4($sp)
       jr $ra

  endCondition:
       li $v0, 2
       b cleanUp
```

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Where is the function for `F(n)`? Shouldn't there be a call to it since this is recursive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgotten to shrink the stack at the end of the `fastfunc` procedure.

Just before `jr $ra` I added `addi $sp $sp 8`, then it started halting as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your return address `$ra` is loading `0x00400050` (from factfunc) instead of `0x00400020` (from main). It's a quick fix to add to `$sp$`.